# How to open vb.net copied/transferred codes?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, file-transfer, file-copying

I have copied the folder which includes my code in Visual basic.net 2005 (form1.vb, form1.desing.vb and form1.resx) to my cooldisk. Now, I need to open it in another machine. I click on "open project" option in vb.net 2008, but it asks for *.vbp file which is not in the folder I have copied! When I open the by clicking on them, the form (interface) is not appeared and I only can see the code. I need to edit the interface (visual form), how can I open it correctly?

Comment: isn't vbp the VB6 project format?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new project and add the existing forms to it.